# Как добавить вкладку instagram в виджет на wordpress?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, виджет

Всем привет! Хочу добавить вкладку инстаграма в виджет на wordpress. Делаю по аналогии с контактом, есть пример как должно выглядеть, но пока не пойму на какие поля/переменные необходимо заменить
Код ниже:

```html
<?php public function vk_output() { $show_vk_box=m ad_custom_get_option( 'show_vk_box'); $vk_title=h tmlspecialchars(mad_custom_get_option( 'vk_title')); $vk_widget_community=h tml_entity_decode(mad_custom_get_option( 'vk_widget_community')); if ($show_vk_box):
?>
<li>
  <button class="panel-button instagram"></button>

  <div class="admin-panel-content">

    <?php if (!empty($vk_title)): ?>
    <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo esc_html($vk_title); ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php ?>

    <?php if (strpos($vk_widget_community, 'vk.com/js/api/')) { echo $vk_widget_community; } ?>

  </div>
  <!--/ .admin-panel-content-->
</li>
<?php endif; } ?>

/* Должен получиться такой вывод */
<li>
  <button class="panel-button instagram"></button>
  <div class="admin-panel-content">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Instagram</h3>
    <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?h=YW1hemluZ3xpbnw1NXw0fDR8fG5vfDJ8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fHllc3xubw==&amp;ve=300415" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;width:228px;height:228px"></iframe>
  </div>
  <!--/ .admin-panel-content-->
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, решил сам- может кому-нить пригодится:

```html
public function instagram_output() { ?>
<li>
  <button class="panel-button instagram"></button>
  <div class="admin-panel-content">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Instagram</h3>
    <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?h=YW1hemluZ3xpbnw1NXw0fDR8fG5vfDJ8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fHllc3xubw==&amp;ve=300415" title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;width:228px;height:228px"></iframe>
  </div>
  <!--/ .admin-panel-content-->
</li>
<?php } <!--добавил в список-->
<div class="aside-admin-panel">

  <ul>
    <?php $this->vk_output(); ?>
    <?php $this->facebook_output(); ?>
    <?php $this->latest_tweets_output(); ?>
    <?php $this->contact_us_output(); ?>
    <?php $this->store_location_output(); ?>
    <?php $this->instagram_output(); ?>
  </ul>
```